# A massive synonym

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, no-computers

Please explain how to assemble the puzzle.
Yes, one is missing, but you can follow the >.
No computers.

[image: puzzle]

Hint:

> No rotations, the letters are oriented correctly. One option is to solve the blue first.  If you noticed the blue letters could be made to form a line, you are in a good spot.

Hint 2:

> NMNDL. This puzzle is not accepting donations, it is just about assembly. The title is your guide.

Hint 3:

> Mr. Agana has some advice: "Keep it simple." Try cutting out the pieces and shuffling them around? If you noticed 'A' must follow 'M', you are in a good place. Solve one row and you will have what you need to continue.

Text version:

```
2 wide by 4 high (x6)
O |A |ND|OE|A |E |  
 U             E 
N  MA AA I   U L 
 I  A IA U

4 wide by 2 high (x3)
   I|   A| IEO
  A |  A |> A 
Target:
12 wide by 6 high in blocks of 4x3
```

Comment: Why one is missing? 8X9 = 12X6 = 72. What is the drawing below the 2X4 blocks?

Comment: @Moti What is missing will be realized when the puzzle is solved, but a creative person might leverage that fact as a clue. The empty grid is the target shape.

Comment: Here my brain is trying to do an unscramble puzzle. It found "NOMAD". Lol

Comment: @Riddler Correct strategy. But think about the puzzle as a whole.

Comment: I have two candidates for the blues but am yet to spot if either is significant: rot13(ZVAQOBTTYVAT, n 'tvnag' flabalz juvpu cyrnfvatyl svgf gur shyy tevq jvqgu (ohg yrnirf n 2k2 nern va gur obggbz yrsg pbeare) be cneg bs vg fcryyvat ZNELYNAQ, juvpu zvtug vaqvpngr gung HF fgngrf ner uvqqra urer...)

Comment: A perhaps more robust theory: rot13(Gur pbybhe-pbqvat fhttrfgf gb zr gung jr ner ybbxvat sbe n tevq shyy bs eryngrq jbeqf gung fanxr sbegu-naq-onpx nybat rnpu ebj, hcjneqf sebz gur obggbz-yrsg pbeare. Gur oyhrf fubhyq pbafgvghgr n fvatyr jbeq tbvat yrsgjneqf naq ortvaavat jvgu Z naq pbagnvavat Y, A naq QA. Nygbtrgure gur jbeq frg (juvpu vf zvffvat bar zrzore) jvyy or eryngrq gb 'znffvir', r.t. gvgnavp sbe n yvfg bs Gvgnaf sebz zlgubybtl.) For this to be right we just need to work out (a) what set, and (b) which members contain 'OEI' and 'AA' substrings!

Comment: @Stiv You are nearly there. But I think you meant ND.

Comment: I actually did mean DN not ND if we are to assume the path snakes through the grid, as in that row the text would be flowing from right to left if my theory above is correct. (By the sound of your response though I'm not quite in alignment yet...)

Comment: @Stiv The rules are a bit simpler than that, hence the no computers which makes it almost trivial... without a computer I feel it is tricky enough without being too difficult...

Comment: High quality puzzle. Thanks for making it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can

> fit the pieces in to the target grid like this
>  [image]
>  or with the target grids block division
>  [image]
>
>  We can immediately notice here two things. First of all, the third row with all the blue letters spells **MAINLAND**. Secondly, the yellow and green letters are in alternating blocks.
>
>  Each block actually contains all the vowels of a continent's name and the continents are also more or less in the regular order of a world map. I.e., we have
>  **North America**, **Europe**, **Asia**
>  **South America**, **Africa**, **Australia**
>
>  The one we are missing is **Antarctica**, but that can be read from the bottom row as indicated by the arrow.

Comment: You got it, well done!